# Cordova app repository - Should there be one for both iOS and Android or separate?

Tags: cordova, hybrid

I have been given the task to maintain a cordova based app having both iOS and Android version. There are two separate repositories provided to me, i.e. one for iOS and one for Android. 
Since, it is cordova based app, I am planning to convert it into one single repository and having both iOS and Android under platforms folder. Though I am not sure if there is any downside of converting this into one repository OR is there any advantage of keeping separate repositories for Android and iOS for a cordova based app. Please advice.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All files you will work on will reside in the main `www` folder inside the root project folder. When you use commands like `cordova build ios`, this copies all the files from your `www` folder into their respective platforms/ios or platforms/android. So yes, if you support both the iOS and Android platforms, you should see both of those folders in the `platforms` folder, but you should never work in those folders

Comment: So, technically I don't need to maintain the two repositories. I can go ahead with one only ?

Comment: @LetsLearn correct! All your files you will work on will reside in the `www` folder in your root Cordova project